# Weird title on inputs / textareas all around the web

Tags: html

When I mouse over many inputs and textareas *all over the web,* I see some weird text.

[image: issue on SE]

I thought it was on StackExchange only, but it happens on amazon:

[image: on amazon, too]

(note that you can't see my mouse in these pictures, it is not recorded in the screenshot, but it is on the upper-left of each hover text.

Chrome's DevTools shows a weird title attribute:

[image]

I have **no idea** why this happens. The websites I've seen this on don't seem to have a library in common, so I doubt that would cause the problem. At the same time, I have seen this in browsers other than chrome, so I don't know. Even the textarea that I'm typing in *right now* has the problem.

## Why does this happen and how can I prevent it from happening to my website?

Comment: "I have seen this in browsers other than chrome" means that you're getting it in all browsers, so it cannot be a Chrome extension?

Comment: Whatever, it feels a Chrome thing anyway: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/9wK-mvIzeAg

Answer (score 1):

Looks like that's a built-in Chrome option, an "experimental feature." Go to chrome://flags/ and disable "Show Autofill predictions" if you want to turn it off (mine was disabled by default).